# Deploying Atlassian's Confluence onto openshift?

Tags: jboss, openshift, confluence

Does anyone know how to deploy Confluence onto OpenShift? I tried following the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF31/Installing+Confluence+EAR-WAR+on+JBoss#InstallingConfluenceEAR-WARonJBoss-Step1.ConfiguringtheConfluenceWarFile) but am stuck at configuring the confluence-init.properties.

Comment: Don't forget to ask for a medium gear to do this - you need at least that much memory

Comment: so [this form?](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/page/resource-request-form) and one medium gear?

Comment: Exactly and just ask for medium gears to run Confluence. No need to specifiy the number. 
You may want to make the app scalable so that the DB will be on another gear - but that is a bit more complicated to set up.

Would be great if you blogged the instructions if you get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set the directory for home dir to the following environment variable - OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. That dir will persist between git pushes and between shutdown and startup of the app.

Here are instructions on how to fill out your JNDI setting
https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/jndi-tomcat-configuration-howto

Comment: Quick question, do you recommend using a JBOSS cartridge or Tomcat? I don't have much experience with either as I usually just use their confluence distribution package.

Comment: Tomcat should be more than enough (unless you need JEE6 features)

Comment: I just realized I may have added it wrong, is it supposed to be
`confluence.home=${env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}`